# how to make particles follow my mouse in pygame

Tags: python, math, pygame

I'm trying to make sure that the particles that arise when I click my mouse follow my mouse. For some reason, the particles just follow me to the top left. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import math

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
particles = []
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            particles.append([[pygame.Rect(mx,my,10,10)]])
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
    for particle in particles:
        mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),particle[0][0])
        radians = math.atan2((particle[0][0].y - my),(particle[0][0].x -mx))
        dy1 = math.sin(radians)
        dx1 = math.cos(radians)
        particle[0][0].x -= dx1
        particle[0][0].y -= dy1
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused, because [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) stores integral values. If you add an floating point value, then the fraction part gets  lost and the result is truncated. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the resulting coordinates to solve the issue:

```py
particle[0][0].x = round(particle[0][0].x - dx1)
particle[0][0].y = round(particle[0][0].y - dy1)
```

---

Note, it is sufficient to append a `pygame.Rect` object to the list, rather than a list of a list of `pygame.Rect`:

<s>`particles.append([[pygame.Rect(mx,my,10,10)]])`</s>

```py
particles.append(pygame.Rect(mx,my,10,10))
```

---

Example:

```py
particles = []
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            particles.append(pygame.Rect(mx, my, 10, 10))
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
    for particle in particles:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), particle)
        radians = math.atan2(my - particle.y, mx - particle.x)
        particle.x = round(particle.x + math.cos(radians))
        particle.y = round(particle.y + math.sin(radians))
```

---

For an even more sophisticated approach see [How to make smooth movement in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087982/how-to-make-smooth-movement-in-pygame/64088747?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 1):

It works with a simple adjustment:

```
    dy1 = math.sin(radians) * 10
    dx1 = math.cos(radians) * 10
```

The problem is that you try to move the particles for less than a pixel at a time which results in them not moving at all and the movement being lost.