# Pygame sprite not turning accordingly to mouse

Tags: python, pygame, rotation, mouse

I've been trying and trying, but basically I wanna make a tank game which has a tank that can turn itself by the mouse to fire bullets; when you turn your mouse to a direction, the sprite will follow exactly. the problem is, I can't turn the tank with any code, no matter what.

```
import os
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (0, 30)
icon = pygame.image.load('Sprite3.png')
pygame.display.set_icon((icon))
pygame.display.set_caption('DeMass.io')

class Tank(object):  # represents the bird, not the game
    def __init__(self):
        """ The constructor of the class """
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
        # the bird's position
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def handle_keys(self):
        """ Handles Keys """
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] or key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.y += dist # move down

        elif key[pygame.K_UP] or key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.y -= dist # move up

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] or key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.x += dist # move right

        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] or key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.x -= dist # move left


def draw(self, surface):
        """ Draw on surface """
        # blit yourself at your current position
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

w = 1900
h = 10000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

tank = Tank() # create an instance
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
connection_angle = 90

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() # quit the screen
            running = False
    
    
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  
    tank.draw(screen)  
    pygame.display.update()  
    tank.handle_keys() 
    clock.tick(100)
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code about moving the tank with the mouse. It uses wasd and arrow keys

Comment: Do you want to *move* the tank to the mouse-cursor, or have it *turn* towards the mouse-cursor?  Or have the tank's Turret turn to face the cursor?  Should the tank instantly turn to the mouse-cursor, or begin turning to that direction with some speed?  Please be exact in your requirement.

Comment: @drum  srry if i was a bit unclear. I want to add an extra function in this code so that the sprite turns with the mouse. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `atan2` function from the built-in `math` module to calcualte the angle between two coordinates,
and then rotate your sprite accordingly:

```
import pygame
from math import atan2, degrees

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(185, 180))

    def point_at(self, x, y):
        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, degrees(atan2(x-self.rect.x, y-self.rect.y)))
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        wn.fill((0, 0, 0))
        wn.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

player = Player()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            player.point_at(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    pygame.display.update()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to move the sprite as well? Thanks!

Comment: @BetterNot You mean make it follow the mouse?

Comment: @BetterNot see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087982/how-to-make-smooth-movement-in-pygame/64088747#64088747

Comment: @AnnZen Uh not quite, I hope to use "WASD" to move the sprite and the mouse to turn the sprite at the same time. I got the "WASD" part, but not the turning with mouse. Is it possible to put these two functions together? PS, is it possible to change the image into something else? Thanks!