# How do I rotate a sprite towards the mouse and move it?

Tags: python, pygame, position, pygame-surface

I'm confused by the fact that in my code the sprite's coordinates don't seem to change where it is. Putting `(200, 200)` would be the same as putting (900, 100000). So basically i cannot coordinate the sprite in a designated position. Can you help?

Turning credits to Ann Zen
But the sprite problems on me
[Pygame sprite not turning accordingly to mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795438/pygame-sprite-not-turning-accordingly-to-mouse/64796531?noredirect=1#comment114577126_64796531)

My code:

```
import pygame
from math import atan2, degrees
# tank = pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()



    def point_at(self, x, y):
        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, degrees(atan2(x-self.rect.x, y-self.rect.y)))
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        wn.fill((255, 255, 255))
        wn.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)




player = Player()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            player.point_at(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    # wn.blit(tank, Player)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: "Putting (200, 200) would be the same as putting (900, 100000)" Putting it *where*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the answer to [How to rotate an image(player) to the mouse direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603835/how-to-rotate-an-imageplayer-to-the-mouse-direction) carefully. The calculation of the angle

> ```py
> degrees(atan2(x-self.rect.x, y-self.rect.y))
> ```

works by chance. It works, because `atan2(x, y) == atan2(-y, x)-pi/2`.

The angle of a vector (*x*, *y*) is `atan2(y, x)`. The y-axis needs to be reversed (`-y`) as the y-axis is generally pointing up, but in the PyGame coordinate system the y-axis is pointing down. Most likely your *Sprite* points upwards and you want to compute:

```py
angle = degrees(atan2(self.rect.y - y, x - self.rect.x)) - 90
```

respectively

```py
direction = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y) - self.rect.center
angle = direction.angle_to((0, -1))
```

See also [How to know the angle between two points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258637/how-to-know-the-angle-between-two-points/64563327#64563327)

---

The *Sprite* is drawn at the location stored in `rect` attribute. You don't need the `x` and `y` attribute at all. Just set the location of the rectangle (`rect`).
Add *x*  and *y* arguments to the constructor:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
```

Add a method `move` and use [`pygame.Rect.move_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) to change the position of the *Sprite*:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rect.move_ip(x, y)
```

Invoke `move`, when you want to change the position of the *Sprite*:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_w]:
    player.move(0, -1)
if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    player.move(0, 1)
if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    player.move(-1, 0)
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    player.move(1, 0)
```

respectively

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
player.move(keys[pygame.K_d]-keys[pygame.K_a], keys[pygame.K_s]-keys[pygame.K_w])
```

A *Sprite* should always be contained in a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect` for the position.

Add a *Group* and add the *Sprite* to the *Group*:

```py
player = Player(200, 200)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)
```

Invoke `draw` when you want to draw all the *Sprites* in the *Group*:

```py
all_sprites.draw(wn)
```

Ensure that the rotated image is stored in the `image` attribute:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))

    def point_at(self, x, y):
        direction = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y) - self.rect.center
        angle = direction.angle_to((0, -1))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    # [...]
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteRotateToMouse](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteRotateToMouse#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.velocity = 5

    def point_at(self, x, y):
        direction = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y) - self.rect.center
        angle = direction.angle_to((0, -1))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rect.move_ip(x * self.velocity, y * self.velocity)


player = Player(200, 200)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    player.point_at(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.move(keys[pygame.K_d]-keys[pygame.K_a], keys[pygame.K_s]-keys[pygame.K_w])

    wn.fill((255, 255, 255))
    all_sprites.draw(wn)
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

If you want to move the object in the direction of the mouse, then you have to add a `direction` and `position` attribute of type [`pygame.math.Vecotr2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2). The direction is changed in `point_at` and the position is changet in `move`, dependent on the direction. The `rect` attribute has to be updated.

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteFollowMouse](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteFollowMouse#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2((0, -1))
        self.velocity = 5
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)

    def point_at(self, x, y):
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y) - self.rect.center
        if self.direction.length() > 0:
            self.direction = self.direction.normalize()
        angle = self.direction.angle_to((0, -1))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.position -= self.direction * y * self.velocity
        self.position += pygame.math.Vector2(-self.direction.y, self.direction.x) * x * self.velocity
        self.rect.center = round(self.position.x), round(self.position.y)


player = Player(200, 200)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            player.point_at(*event.pos)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.move(keys[pygame.K_d]-keys[pygame.K_a], keys[pygame.K_s]-keys[pygame.K_w])

    wn.fill((255, 255, 255))
    all_sprites.draw(wn)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:` block, and put the `player.point_at(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())` directly into the `while` loop.

Create a clock so that the sprite won't zip out of the screen.

Finally, add

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.rect.y -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.rect.y += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.rect.x -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.rect.x += 1
```

to control the player.

Example:

```
import pygame
from math import atan2, degrees

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(185, 180))

    def point_at(self, x, y):
        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, degrees(atan2(x-self.rect.x, y-self.rect.y)))
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        wn.fill((0, 0, 0))
        wn.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock() # Create the clock

while True:
    clock.tick(30) # Use the clock
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() # Get al the pressed keys
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.rect.y -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.rect.y += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player.rect.x -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.rect.x += 1
        
    player.point_at(*pygame.mouse.get_pos()) # Put this here
    pygame.display.update()
```

Output:

[image]