# Make moving more realistic

Tags: python, pygame

I made this code to make a circle follow my mouse but the movement is really mechanic and does not give the 360 degrees of movement I desired.

Here's the code:

```
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        Running = False

mpos = (mx, my)
X = (playerX)
Y = (playerY)


if mpos[1] >= Y: 
    playerY += vel


if mpos[1] <= Y:
    playerY -= vel

    
if mpos[0] <= X:
    playerX -= vel

if mpos[0] >= X:
    playerX += vel
```

Comment: See also [How to make smooth movement in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087982/how-to-make-smooth-movement-in-pygame/64088747#64088747) and [pygame 2 dimensional movement of an enemy towards the player, how to calculate x and y velocity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66404707/pygame-2-dimensional-movement-of-an-enemy-towards-the-player-how-to-calculate-x/66406985#66406985).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the direction [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector), normalize it and multiply it with the desired speed, then apply that to the circles position.

The easiest way is to use pygame's built-in `Vector2` class for this:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
    pos = pygame.Vector2()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    speed = 10
    while True:
        
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return 
                
        movement = pygame.mouse.get_pos() - pos 
        if movement.length() > 6: # some margin so we don't flicker between two coordinates
            if movement.length() > 0: # when we move, we want to move at a constant speed
                movement.normalize_ip()
            pos += movement * speed # change the position
    
        screen.fill((20, 20, 20))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'dodgerblue', pos, 30)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
        
main()
```

[image]